# Perform Insert/Update/Query/Delete operations on Force.com records via Excel

Tags: apex, office-connect, excel

Scenario: I am looking at a viable approach to insert/update/query/delete records in Force.com right from a predefined Excel Template. These operations will have to be done by the End Users.

Researched on Excel Connector, but its not user friendly and cannot be rolled out to end users in the current form. It requires heavy customization to enable the users perform the above operations and to avoid intermittent error messages.

Questions:
Is there any other Tool which helps achieve the requirement?
Has anyone customized the Excel Connector with an intent to roll it out to end users?
Is it possible to read the contents of an Excel file from Force.com Application via Apex?
Is it possible to extract the records into an predefined Excel Template via Apex?

Answer (score 3):

As far as I am aware there is nothing other than the Excel Connector you mention, and agree its a bit raw, being SOQL based etc.

**Visual Studio Tools for Office and Partner WSDL** You might have to resort to developing an Excel Addin customised for your own needs, via [VSTO](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/d2tx7z6d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx). VisualStudio and .Net has excellent Web Service support allowing you to import the Partner WSDL and use the generated code and the Excel object model to build something yourself. Such Addins can be distributed via a single Excel template file to your users.

**Apex Handling of Office Files**. As it happens I wrote a blog around handling Excel files (well Open Office files in general). You can read about it [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/12/09/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-2/) and [here](http://andyinthecloud.com/2012/11/04/handling-office-files-and-zip-files-in-apex-part-1/). It also covers generating files as well. There is a couple of architecture options, the most flexible is covered in part 2. The screen shots below are from part 1.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Andrew for the insights, I have a couple of questions:
For my problem can I baseline the existing Excel Connector code and build on it to achieve my requirements. (Or) To start building the connector from scratch using VSTO. Which one you recommend?

Comment: Second, the post "Handling Zip Files" was extremely helpful as we have another requirement to automatically Zip the files and to protect them with a password? Is Password Protection on Files possible (the key can be one of the Fields from the User Record, for instance email/custom Field etc...?

Comment: RE: Baseline existing code for Excel Connector. That maybe an option, I've not looked at that code. It do know its likely to be quite old and may struggle to support 64bit. Personally I would use the latest Microsoft Office integration approaches and write specific queries and updates for your use case. The generic code in the connector will probably not serve you all that well and just get in the way of you doing something more specific. IMHO. :)

Comment: RE: Handling Zip files, thanks for the feedback. The VF components i developed wrap the JSZip library, just checking the site for that library, currently it does not support generating password protected zip files. Sorry. http://stuk.github.com/jszip/

Comment: Andrew, had a detailed look at "Handling Zip Files" part 2 and understood that xlsx is essentially a group of XML files zipped into one, which when unzipped using your component could be processed in Apex. 
Could you pls help me understand if the above is true and how to specifically locate the xml containing the actual xslx data and the parsing mechanism? Does the same apply for xlsm?

Comment: Yep you've got it, for XSLX files, the sheet data is in /xl/worksheets/sheet1.xml etc.. There is a manifest in /xl/workbook.xml. You can then use the standard Apex XML parsing support to get at the data. I've done a bit of digging and XLSM files also appear to be in the Open Office format so should work much the same. Easy way is to rename the file extension to .zip and try to unzip it! :)

Answer (score 1):

if anyone else stumbles on this old question, as well as GridBuddy & Apsona that provide a grid style element into SF interface, a newer product does full excel integration:  **XAuthor by Apptus**.

With xAuthor users work in a pre-configured spreadsheet in which columns link back to SF fields. All Excel functions can be used and data entry honors validation and workflow rules.  Also supports cross-object data entry.

Comment: Can you please clarify either way if you are affiliated with this product or not?

Answer (score 0):

While I'm not sure of tools that meet your exact requirements, of having it contained in a predefined template, there are some solutions that come quite close to what I think you're trying to achieve.

Both GridBuddy and Apsona on the AppExchange offer mass update/create/insert from a grid view.  These views can be predefined and saved but they are not Excel files as you requested in your post:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003JejzEAC
https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N30000003IkInEAK

Another option is Conga Composer, which offers you the capability of spitting out Salesforce data into a predefined Excel Template:

https://appexchange.salesforce.com/listingDetail?listingId=a0N300000016b7FEAQ

Lastly, there is a pretty good example of uploading data from a CSV file into a Visualforce page and committing it to the database:

http://www.forcetree.com/2010/08/read-and-insert-records-from-csv-file.html

With the last solution, you may be able to build a custom interface yourself but I would take a look at GridBuddy and Apsona first to see if they might meet your needs.

Comment: Thanks indeed, for the extract part as you rightly mentioned we are thinking of using Conga Composer (however licenses are more as this feature should be rolled-out to end users). And for CSV upload we already built the custom solution based on the link you provided plus below link (to workaround the "Regex too complicated" error).

http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/Pattern-and-Matcher-Question/m-p/135986

It should be useful for others building a custom CSV upload feature.